# Placing Markers to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to click on a google map and display the latitude and longitude on a div.

This is my js code:

```
map.instance.addListener('click', function(e) {
  if (map.geozones.length < 50) {
    map.placeMarker(e.latLng);
    $("#geopoint-list").prepend("<br>");
    $("#geopoint-list").prepend("(" + map.markerList[0].position.lat() + ", " + map.markerList[0].position.lng() + ")");
  }
);
```

I've just realize they all share the same position. I think it's because the `addListener` shares the 'e' event. The position it's being display, but they all show the same as the first one I place.

Any idea? 
New here in JS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you use

```
map.markerList[0].position.lat()
```

which will always take the element on position 0 of your markerList.

Comment: Thanks man! You were right. For further information I changed that line for: e.latLng.lat() + ", " + e.latLng.lng()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
map.instance.addListener('click', function(e) {
  if (map.geozones.length < 50) {
    map.placeMarker(e.latLng);
    $("#geopoint-list").prepend("<br>");
    $("#geopoint-list").prepend("(" + e.latLng.lat() + ", " + e.latLng.lng() + ")");
  }
);
```

Comment: Your answer it's also correct. I've just accepted the other one just before